# Chomsky form for language of single alphabet member

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, formal-grammars, normal-forms

I'm a bit confused as to how to represent the Chomsky form for the language L that generates all strings with the alphabet {a}

My approach was

```
S -> AB | e
A -> a
```

Now here's the part I'm confused, how do I represent B? If B -> a then I get only even strings, if B -> e then it's not in normal form. :| Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar is similar to what you say:
$$
S \rightarrow S S \mid a
$$
This can't generate $\epsilon$, which any true CFG can't.

Comment: This is still regular, right?

Comment: The _language_ is regular, the _grammar_ isn't. No Chomsky Normal Form grammar is regular (except for the trivial ones with only productions $S \rightarrow a$).